# How to read multiple csv files with specific name from a folder and merge them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, csv

I am trying to read multiple files from a folder with specific name (1.car.csv, 2.car.csv and so on) and trying to add a new label after each iteration at right most of the dataset and merge all the csv files into one csv file. As the ".car.csv" is constant, I think I can use a for loop with .format(index) function to run over the csv files. All of the csv files has got same attributes.

Kindly help me!

Answer (score 2):

- `glob` is used to get all files in the folder that match the pattern `*.csv`
- `pd.read_csv` is used to read each file as a DataFrame

  - `index_col=None` you are telling Pandas to not use any of the columns as the index, and instead to create a default index for the DataFrame.
  - `header=0` you are telling Pandas to use the first row of the CSV file as the header row.
- `pd.concat` is used to merge all the DataFrames into a single DataFrame `merged_df`

  - `axis=0` means that the concatenation should happen along the rows (vertically)
  - `ignore_index=True` the concatenation is performed such that the original indices of the individual DataFrames are discarded, and a new default index is created for the resulting DataFrame.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = r'<path to folder containing csv files>'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

lst = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    lst.append(df)

merged_df = pd.concat(lst, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with a CSV tool like [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller):

```
mlr --csv cat --filename bla1.csv *.car.csv
```

This will concatenate the files (without repeating the header) and prepend the filename as the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Using pathlib and pandas you can use .assign() to enter the new column and finally .concat() to concatenate all the files into one.

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


input_path = Path("path/to/car/files/").glob("*car.csv")
output_path = "path/to/output"

pd.concat(
    (pd.read_csv(x).assign(new_label="new data") for x in input_path), ignore_index=True
).to_csv(f"{output_path}/final.csv", index=False)
```